# "sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user"

Tags: python, database, flask

I am getting this error right after I click the submit button which is on sign-up page. I have created a .db file and the User class is declared on models.py file with its properties.

Here is some more details of the error:
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (email, password, first_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <title>{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>      
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="login" href="/login">Login</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="signUp" href="/sign-up">Sign up</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="logout" href="/logout">Logout</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="home" href="/">Home</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %} {% if
      messages %} {% for category, message in messages %} {% if category ==
      'error' %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger alter-dismissable fade show" role="alert">
          {{ message }}
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <div class="alert alert-success alter-dismissable fade show" role="alert">
          {{ message }}
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        {% endif %} {% endfor %} {% endif %} {% endwith %}
    
        <div class="container">{% block content %} {% endblock %}</div>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}"
    ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

sign_up.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}Sign Up{% endblock %} {% block
    content %}
    <form method="POST">
      <h3 align="center">Sign Up</h3>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <input
          type="email"
          class="form-control"
          id="email"
          name="email"
          placeholder="Enter email"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="firstName"
          name="firstName"
          placeholder="Enter first name"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password1">Password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          class="form-control"
          id="password1"
          name="password1"
          placeholder="Enter password"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password2">Password (Confirm)</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          class="form-control"
          id="password2"
          name="password2"
          placeholder="Confirm password"
        />
      </div>
      <br />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

__ init __.py

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path

db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'asdfghhjkl'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
    db.init_app(app)

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')

    from .models import User, Note

    create_database(app)
    
    return app

def create_database(app):
    if not path.exists('website/' + DB_NAME):
        db.create_all(app = app)
        print('Created Database!')
```

auth.py

```
from typing import Text
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug.wrappers import request as werkzeug_request
from .models import User
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash 
from . import db


auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    return render_template("login.html", boolean=True)


@auth.route('/logout')
def logout():
    return "<p>logout</p>"

@auth.route('/sign-up', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sign_up():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        first_name = request.form.get('firstName')
        password1 = request.form.get('password1')
        password2 = request.form.get('password2')

        if len(email) < 4:
            flash('Email must be greater than 4 characters', category='error')
        elif len(first_name) < 2:
            flash('First name must be greater than 2 characters', category='error')
        elif password1 != password2:
            flash('Passwords don\'t match', category='error')
        elif len(password1) < 8:
            flash('Password must contain at least 8 characters', category='error')
        else:
            new_user = User(email=email, first_name=first_name, password=generate_password_hash(password1, method='sha256'))
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()       
            flash('Account created!', category="success")
            return redirect(url_for('views.home'))

    return render_template("sign_up.html")
```

models.py

```
from datetime import timezone
from . import db 
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

class Note(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    data = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone = True), default = func.now())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique = True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    notes = db.relationship('Note')
```

views.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

views = Blueprint('views', __name__)

@views.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't imported `models` before that `db.create_all()`, there'll be nothing to create. Then things get confusing later in code that has imported `models`, since that code will construct queries that assume a populated database.